# How do I get rid of this error? TypeError: Cannot set property 'onfocus' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, onblur, onfocus

So I have this angular component for an `<input>` form field, for a pattern library. I set up all the necessary parts for it to display and function. However, I added some functionality to raise the `<label>`and keep the `<label>` raised when text is inputed in the field or `onfocus` and the `<label>` should stay raised `onblur` if there is text in the `<input>` text field. The code was working a few days ago and nothing has changed. Here is the HTML component:

```
            <div class="regular-text" id="regularFormField">
                <a href="{{HelperUrl}}" *ngIf="HelperUrl">{{HelperUrltext}}</a>          
                <span *ngIf="state == 'Validation'" class="valid"><img src="../../assets/01-green-validate-check.png" alt="valid icon">{{ValidMssg}}Valid bank number</span>
                <span *ngIf="state == 'Error'" class="error" id="wrongText"><img src="../../assets/error-icon.svg" alt="error icon">{{ErrorMssg}}We don’t recognize this email. Please try again.</span>
                <input type="{{FormType}}" id="email" aria-label="" [ngClass]="{'disabled': state == 'Disabled', 'error': state == 'Error', 'valid': state == 'Validation'}" [attr.disabled]="state == 'Disabled' ? 'disabled' : null">
                <label for="{{FormType}}" aria-label="" id="labelone" [ngClass]="{'disable-text': state == 'Disabled'}">{{FormType}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the JS code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const input = document.getElementById("email");

    const formOutline = document.getElementById("regularFormField");
    const label = document.getElementById("labelone");

    input.onfocus = () => {
      formOutline.classList.add("focused");

    };

    input.onblur = () => {
      formOutline.classList.remove("focused");
      label.classList.add("active");

      const inputValue = (<any>document).getElementById("email").value;

      if (inputValue == "") {

        label.classList.remove("active");
      }
    };
  } // ng init


Is there anything missing? I know a fresh set of eyes helps.
```

Comment: Try using Angular. Handle the `focus` event with `(focus)="myFocusHandler()`. Set classes using `[class.active]="activeCondition"`. You should rarely - if ever - need to manually alter the DOM

Comment: Because your retirement probably doesn't exist yet when you call the code. You should rather use angular event hooks for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM inspector and `console.log` statements to inspect, debug, and identify the problem, then trace it to the source.

When your JS code runs, `input` is null. That means no element was found with the id "email".

Put console.log above input to verify this. Then manually inspect the DOM elements in the inspector to see if it is there. Go from there.

The comments about changing your app architecture may be good advice - I don't do Angular - but basic debugging techniques to narrow it down are essential to mastering your craft.

You should get flat on what happened here. If it really was working and suddenly stopped, then either you did make a change that you are not aware of, or something else is going on. Either way, you want to understand your code base and its operation - and if you did do something that caused this, you want to know what it was, otherwise you are likely to do the same thing somewhere else, and your experience of programming will be frustrating.